# Appending multiple HTML elements without using .html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to inject a chat message each time I send one to the server. Each chat message contains a username, an avatar and a message. How do I append multiple HTML elements using jQuery? With this code, it worked, but I'm afraid of using .html because now users can send a message like `"<i>Italic</i>"` which is displayed as HTML also for other users. With only one element I've used .text which solves this security issue, but I was only able to include a very simple construct without using an avatar or any styles

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var username = '<%= user.name %>'; // Username is stored in Session, using EJS to set this
    var avatar = '<%= user.avatar_small %>'; // Avatar is stored in Session, using EJS to set this
    var message = $("#message").val(); // getting message from input field

    $("#chatList").append(
    $("<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-dark'></li>").html("<img src='"+avatar+"' alt='Avatar' /><label>"+username+":</label> "+message));

    // Socket.io used here to send information to the server
    socket.emit("message", {
        username: username
        message: message,
        avatar: avatar
    });
});
```

Comment: Using `.text` is the right idea, what issues are you running into using it instead?

Comment: It's not really formatting correct more like: "<img src='avatar.png' alt='Avatar' /><label>Username:</label> Message" as a plaint text output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to text-escape *each* of the elements whose text you want to set:

```
const $li = $("<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-dark'><img alt='Avatar'><label></label></li>")
$li.find('img').prop('src', avatar);
$li.find('label').text(username + ':')
$li.append(document.createTextNode(message));
$("#chatList").append($li);
```

Comment: Thank you for help, the only issue is that the message is after </li> tag

Comment: Oh, you wanted the message inside, not outside - so, append to the `li`, not the `chatList`